# Control mouse and keyboard from C# Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, x11, xorg

I have been writing a C# app that works fine on Windows. It controls keyboard and mouse, and send keystrokes to the currently open program.

However, I want to port my application to Linux, and therefore I cannot use the MouseKeyboardLibrary.dll I have currently been using is doing very Windows specific things.

Is there a library that makes it easy for me to send keyboard and mouse movements to a program in X11 or Xorg?

Comment: I suspect you'll probably end up having to write your own library for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to find anything already-made. But I found a starting point for you: [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) is a project to control mouse and keyboard from the command line. It's open source as well, so if you wish, you could implement the same functionality natively(or with a few P/Invokes if required) in C#.

Comment: xdotool seems like a viable alternative, I also just stumbled across xte (also known as xautomation) here http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte . They seem rather equal, so thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kasper the only differences I see is that xdotool includes commands for searching for windows and doing things other than straight keyboard and mouse input. It doesn't sound very relevant to your project though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static bool LinuxOS
    {
        get { return Path.DirectorySeparatorChar == '/'; }
    }

    public static void SendKeys(String output)
    {
        if (LinuxOS)
        {
            var args = "";
            switch (output)
            {
                case "{RIGHT}":
                    args = "key Right";
                    break;
                case "{LEFT}":
                    args = "key Left";
                    break;
                default:
                    if (output.StartsWith("{") && output.EndsWith("}"))
                        output = output.Substring(1, output.Length - 2);

                    args = "type \"" + output + "\"";
                    break;
            }

            var proc = new Process
                       {
                               StartInfo =
                               {
                                       FileName = "xdotool",
                                       Arguments = args,
                                       UseShellExecute = false,
                                       RedirectStandardError = false,
                                       RedirectStandardInput = false,
                                       RedirectStandardOutput = false
                               }
                       };
            proc.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(output);
        }
    }
```